# how to load json data on every item of listview and display the data fetched in another activity in android?

Tags: android, json, listview, android-intent, android-activity

I have a listview and need to fetch data through every item click of listview and display the data in another activity, please let me know the solution

Answer (score 0):

had onclick listener in your itemview holder then pass data using intent to next activity